# Get version number of other ios application

Tags: ios, app-store

Is there any way to check version number of other application which is installed from appstore ?

**Note: 
1. Not in jail broken devices 
2. With out using third party library.**

Comment: No, you can't. You can detect the presence of some apps by URL schemes, but that isn't foolproof, and that won't give you any information about version.

Comment: Can I register my application for receiving notification for update of other application?

Comment: Without jailbreaking, an app cannot receive any information about any other apps installed on the device.

There is some limited inter-app communication available through URL schemes, but that only can work if 2 apps are designed specifically to communicate with the other.

Comment: Hi, is there any update or way to get version of other app? did you get solution? @jailani

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Not Possible. your control is upto the level of your App Sandbox.**

**[What is Sandbox?](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/TheiOSEnvironment/TheiOSEnvironment.html)**

For security reasons, iOS places each app (including its preferences and data) in a sandbox at install time. A sandbox is a set of fine-grained controls that limit the app’s access to files, preferences, network resources, hardware, and so on. As part of the sandboxing process, the system installs each app in its own sandbox directory, which acts as the home for the app and its data.

[image]

Comment: Hi, is there any update or way to get version of other app? @Vijay-Apple-Dev.blogspot.com ?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to check version of another application as in IOS, Applications work in SandBox environment which doesn't allow the application to access other application.

Two applications can communicate with the help of URL schemes,following is the link for URL Schemes of few Applications:

http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes

http://handleopenurl.com/

using URL schemes we can access limited information(Exposed by the Developers of that application)

Although , there are few options,
1)If two application are using same/common web-services ,then this information can be shared
2)using ICloud this can be achieved If two application are using common/public space.